# How to Insert Data in Database if it has Quotes or apostrophe

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am taking the input of address from the user in my existing application.

The issue which is coming often is that the user enters any apostrophe or quotation in data due to which exception occurs.

**For example :**

The user input is :

PLOT # B-102 BLOCK **'C'**

Due to the quotes, exception occurs when the data is inserted in database as it looks the syntax mistake in oracle database.

I gone through the following example:

```
INSERT INTO Person
    (First, Last)
VALUES
    ('Joe', 'O''Brien')
              /\
          right here
```

But it depends upon the location where the apostrophe will be inserted , but in my case I don't know whether and where will the user will try to insert such quotations.

How can I handle this ?

Can anyone please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Address = Replace(Address , "'", "''")` ,replcaing apostrophe  with double quotes should do the trick.Sql will understand and  insert it as single apostrophe  only.

Comment: should i use this replace method in c# ?

Comment: there is no such any replace method in c# like this

Comment: just give me a minute,will check again

Comment: oh..my bad, 
`string NewAddress = Address.Replace("'","''");`

Comment: You **urgently** need to read about [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-injection/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the `single quotes` with 2 `single quotes` to `escape` the `single quote`

```
string Address = txtAddress.Text;
Address = Address.Replace("'","''");
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are building your insert statement by concatenating the string. **This is not a good practice.** **Your application will become vulnerable to SQL injections**. You should use parametrized queries to do this.

If you still want to do this, you can use the replace method to replace ' to '' like following code snippet

```
Replace("'", "''")
```

To use parameterized queries check the following links.

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/shorten-development-time-by-using-parameterized-queries-in-adonet/

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/adonet-in-a/0596003617/ch04s04.html

Comment: No, i am not concatenating any thing in the query

Comment: Are you using parameters?

Comment: there is no any replace method in c# who take 3 arguments

Comment: I agree Replace will work, but this is not advisable, your application will have serious security threat open. You should read more on this and should implement the recommended solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this...

```
string address = "PLOT # B-102 BLOCK \'C\'";
```

Details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k4fw5(v=vs.110).aspx